# Toggling a menu in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this bootstrap: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/
I want to change a text on the button "Toggle menu".
I want to have a text "show menu", "hide menu". 
I only found this fragment a code, but I am able to change a name only once. I don't know how to do the second text "show menu" (when the side bar id hidden).

```
<a href="#menu-togglemenu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Hide Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the actual JavaScript code by this code :

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#wrapper').hasClass('toggled')){
        $(this).html('Hide menu');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Show menu');
    }
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: I know that is stipid question, but where shoud I place it. For this bootstrap I can't see dedicated file with JS, so I added to html file this code in tags <script></script> and this is not working. I left this line from the my first post

Comment: At http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/, the JavaScript code is located at the end of the file, in a `<script>` tag.